# Bootstrap navbar li active not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm customizing a free `bootstrap` template and can't get the navigation to work properly.  When you click on a `navbar` `li` it doesn't become `active`.  It looks like the sections aren't scrolling up enough but I'm not sure what's causing this.  If you scroll up after clicking the navigation item you can get the `li` `class` to become `active`.

Here is the navbar html

```
 <!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><b>Pratt</b></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="smothscroll">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#desc" class="smothscroll">Description</a></li>
            <li><a href="#showcase" class="smothScroll">Showcase</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" class="smothScroll">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here are the sections, I've taken out the content.

```
  <section id="home" name="home">
      <div id="headerwrap">
          <div class="container">              
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>

  <section id="desc" name="desc">
      <div id="intro">
          <div class="container">
          </div> 
      </div>
 </section>

  <section id="showcase" name="showcase">      
      <div class="container">
      </div>       
  </section>

  <section id="contact" name="contact">
      <div id="footerwrap">
         <div class="container">
         </div>
      </div>
 </section>
```

main.css

```
body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #555;
  padding-top: 51px !important;

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

You can download the free template [here](http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/pratt), 
If you look at the demo and click around the navigation items you will see that the navbar `li` `class` is not `active` when it is clicked on.

**To see what I am describing follow these steps**

1) Download code (free/open source) from the following link and run locally
http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/pratt

2) Open `index.html`

3) Click on top `navbar` links from left to right (Home->Description->Showcase->Contact) then back from right to left.  You will see how they are not active when they are clicked on in the correct order.

EDIT: I've updated to show the changes I made according to the suggestions to change `body padding-top:51px !important;`, remove duplicate ids, and wrap sections around divs.  Still doesn't work.

EDIT:  Updated link above to where you can download original template that I used.

Comment: You have given same `id` for `section` and `div` i.e. `showcase`.. `id`'s have to be **unique**

Comment: If I change the duplicate `section` id, the problems is still there.  I made it `<section id="showcase" name="showcase"></section><div id="showcase1">...`

Comment: But I am not able to understand one thing.. Why you have empty `sections` in between? Just for navigation purpose?

Comment: Look at my answer, you'll have your solution. I tested it on your site.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I'm using a template, that's how it was.  Even if I make the sections around the divs it still doesn't work.

Comment: I think you got your answer..  @XahedKamal has posted one..

Comment: make the sections around divs and give the link

Comment: @JSantosh I put sections around divs it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Its just matter of 1px less padding in body tag then nav bar's. Don't make him confused lol! You guys can check it on browser. Just change the body's padding-top:50px to 51px (same height of Navbar's). Simple problem, becoming tough solution!!

Comment: you have duplicate IDs for section and div (`showcase`). fix it. thats the reason when you click in `showcase` its parent li is not getting active class and padding-top is the correct answer as posted by others. try it once

Comment: What is the height of your nav bar?

Comment: div .collapse.navbar-collapse height=50px;

Comment: `active class is not working correctly.` can yo say what are you expecting ?

Answer (score 2):

You are facing this issue cause your `nav`'s height is `51px` but the `padding-top` of `body` is `50px`. Because of `1px` different you are  `active` class in the menu not working correctly.

```
 body{
      padding-top: 51px !important;
 }
```

Remember, `padding-top` has to be exactly same as the height of `navbar` or your navigation's height.

Comment: I changed the `padding-top: 51px;` but it didn't work.  The problem is still there.

Comment: I still see the body tag's padding-top:50px. and every time i change it to 51px, it works fine.

Comment: I've tried it too.  It works when I change the padding-top on the live link with IE developer tools.  But when I change in the main.css in the downloaded code it doesn't work always.

Comment: then use '!important' to force override the css of the template's CSS. Look at the answer, i edited and added '!important'. Use it.

Comment: I also used !important the first time I tried it but it didn't make a difference.  By the way, it's not my code on the live demo.  That's where I got this template from.  Try downloading it and see what happens.  I'm using IE and Firefox.  Haven't testing in Chrome.

Comment: i've just tested it on Chrome as well.. Same way you can fix it. Or do one thing, go to main.css file, change the padding-top to 51px there. It will work. I've it tested in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91690/discussion-between-xahed-kamal-and-heinrich).

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish.

1) Remove `class="smothscroll"` from your links.
2) Add margin-top/padding-top to your body.
3) You shouldn't need call the `containers` and these duplicate IDs are invalid  `<div id="headerwrap">` also.
4) You'll need a JS function to add/remove the active class.

See working example

```js
function scrollNav() {
  $('.navbar a').click(function() {
    //Toggle Class
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
    var theClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $('.' + theClass).parent('li').addClass('active');
    //Animate
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 60
    }, 400);
    return false;
  });
  $('.scrollTop a').scrollTop();
}
scrollNav();
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classie/1.0.1/classie.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><b>VPNVerify</b></a>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#desc">Description</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#showcase">Showcase</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <section id="home">
    <h2>Home</h2>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
    up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
    Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
    in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
    in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
    of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
    from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney
    College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32
    and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor
    at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from
    sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</section>
  <section id="desc">
    <h2>Desc</h2>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
    up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
    Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
    in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
    in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
    of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
    from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney
    College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32
    and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor
    at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from
    sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</section>
  <section id="showcase">
    <h2>Showcase</h2>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
    up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
    Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
    in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
    in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
    of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
    from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney
    College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32
    and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor
    at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from
    sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</section>
  <section id="contact">
    <h2>Contact</h2>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
    up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
    Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
    in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
    in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
    of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
    from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney
    College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32
    and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor
    at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from
    sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```